# how to write test case for a controller in angularJS using jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a angular module in a separate file
**userModule.js**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('users', ['ngRoute','angular-growl','textAngular','ngMaterial','ngMessages','ngImgCrop','ngFileUpload'])
.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $http) {
    $http.get('/token')
        .success(function (user, status) {
        if (user) {
            $rootScope.user = user;
        }
    });
})
```

I've a controller in a separate another file which uses this module:

**userController.js**

```
'use strict';
var usersApp = angular.module('users');

usersApp.controller('usersControllerMain', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams','$location', 'growl','$rootScope','$mdDialog','API',
  function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location,growl,$rootScope,$mdDialog,API) {
    $scope.action = "none";
    $scope.password = '',
    $scope.grade = function() {
      var size = $scope.password.length;
      if (size > 8) {
        $scope.strength = 'strong';
      } else if (size > 3) {
        $scope.strength = 'medium';
      } else {
        $scope.strength = 'weak';
      }
    };
```

i've some dependencies defined in my controller for other uses.

Now i need to test this controller. SO i've written a spec file which i'll run directly in browser. I dont want to use test runners like karma:
**jasmine.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/boot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    describe('userControllerMain testing', function(){

      beforeEach(angular.mock.module('users'));

      var $controller;

      beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$controller_){
            $controller = _$controller_;
        }));
          describe('$scope.grade', function() {
            it('sets the strength to "strong" if the password length is >8 chars', function() {
                var $scope = {};
                var controller = $controller('usersControllerMain', { $scope: $scope });
                $scope.password = 'longerthaneightchars';
                $scope.grade();
                expect($scope.strength).toEqual('strong');
            });
          });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

i took this example from [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing).
but when i run my jasmine.html in browser it throwing an injector module error as shown below:
[image]
. am i doing anything wrong here..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something seriously wrong with the approach that you're following here. You should be mocking the controller inside a `beforeEach` block rather than an `it` block.

So this is how your test file should be:

```
describe('userControllerMain testing', function(){
    beforeEach(module('users'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        usersControllerMain = $controller('usersControllerMain', {
            $scope: $scope
        });
    }));

    describe('$scope.grade', function() {
        it('sets the strength to "strong" if the password length is >8 chars', function() {
            $scope.password = 'longerthaneightchars';
            $scope.grade();
            expect($scope.strength).toEqual('strong');
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.